# jsf, primefaces, jfrechart - Several charts on one page, not displayed each time

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jfreechart, graphicimage

I have the following problem.
I have a jsf page that displays several charts.

JSF:

```
<p:graphicImage value ="#{barChart1}" cache="false"/>
<p:graphicImage value ="#{barChart2}" cache="false"/>
<p:graphicImage value ="#{barChart3}" cache="false"/>`
```

Backing bean:

//example for one chart
Made after this tutorial https://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/dynamic-images-with-jsf/

```
public StreamedContent getBarChart1(){
// jFreeChart generator
return chart = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(chartFile),"image/png");
}
}
```

When the page is loaded it sometimes loads all charts sometimes chart 1 and 2, sometimes chart 1 and 3...

I want all charts to be displayed all the time.

Please help.

Comment: Are the methods called? Are there nothing in the server log or the firebug console? Which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The methods are being called. There is nothing on the server log. If I inspect the page the img tags are there, but if I select the image that is not visible it says can not load image. JSF version is 2.0

Comment: Inspecting the page I get: image corrupt or truncated: